# Where to store static info like about, history, terms, contact info

Tags: mysql, html, apache, web

Where do people store static web page info that does not change often?  Examples are about pages, history, terms, contact info, etc.

Do people normally just code this into the html, or should it be stored in a database?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, They just normally code it in HTML Templates/pages. Database is not needed for such static pages.

Answer (score 0):

yes , it's just HTML file or template file, no need to store in database,
if you want to editable that page from backend then you have to store in database.